# Parse JSON to dataframe returns different numbers

Tags: r, json, dplyr

I have the following JSON:

```
$fraudster
[1] FALSE

$actionType
[1] "LOGIN_FORM"

$actionId
[1] 10

$eventList
[1] "[[1544018118438041139,162.0,38.0,0.023529414,1.0,2131230815,1], [1544018118466235879,162.0,38.0,0.025490198,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018118586849680,161.05167,36.051697,0.023529414,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018118601169211,158.01309,33.01306,0.027450982,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018118612947335,157.0,32.0,0.03137255,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018118614422179,157.0,32.0,0.03137255,1.0,2131230815,-1], [1544018119991079419,195.0,27.0,0.023529414,1.0,2131230815,1], [1544018120055418743,195.0,27.0,0.025490198,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120073841659,195.0,27.0,0.027450982,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120105393170,195.0,29.169312,0.027450982,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120142059888,195.0,30.214783,0.027450982,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120156259680,194.21475,31.0,0.025490198,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120182791659,192.39026,31.30487,0.025490198,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120190025409,187.74063,32.81482,0.023529414,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120205907128,179.21957,35.593445,0.03137255,1.0,2131230815,0], [1544018120207792440,179.21957,35.593445,0.03137255,1.0,2131230815,-1], [1544018133062822643,536.0,86.0,0.025490198,1.0,2131230776,1], [1544018133093266706,535.0,86.0,0.025490198,1.0,2131230776,0], [1544018133143500821,535.0,86.0,0.029411767,1.0,2131230776,0], [1544018133147562227,535.0,86.0,0.029411767,1.0,2131230776,-1]]"

$sensors
[1] "[chb_lin_acc, chb_gra, chb_uncalibrated_gyro]"

$sensorsData
[1] "[[1544018118427051191,-0.8873582,-1.0153246,1.1141882,2.4148588,4.055362,8.596095,0.15446335,-0.058589544,0.2972088], [1544018118427051191,-0.8873582,-1.0153246,1.1141882,2.4160838,4.0595465,8.593774,0.15446335,-0.058589544,0.2972088], [1544018118427051191,-0.8885832,-1.0195088,1.1165094,2.4160838,4.0595465,8.593774,0.15446335,-0.058589544,0.2972088], [1544018118430242389,-0.8885832,-1.0195088,1.1165094,2.4160838,4.0595465,8.593774,0.13315806,-0.014913702,0.31851408], [1544018118437402702,-0.8885832,-1.0195088,1.1165094,2.4160838,4.0595465,8.593774,0.12783173,0.01917476,0.34088463], [1544018118437402702,-0.8885832,-1.0195088,1.1165094,2.421408,4.0530457,8.595345,0.12783173,0.01917476,0.34088463], [1544018118437402702,-0.8939073,-1.0130081,1.1149387,2.421408,4.0530457,8.595345,0.12783173,0.01917476,0.34088463], [1544018118440189837,-0.8939073,-1.0130081,1.1149387,2.421408,4.0530457,8.595345,0.13315806,0.046871636,0.35260254], [1544018118447071400,-0.8939073,-1.0130081,1.1149387,2.421408,4.0530457,8.595345,0.13102753,0.054328486,0.3472762], [1544018118447071400,-0.8939073,-1.0130081,1.1149387,2.4287946,4.0481615,8.595563,0.13102753,0.054328486,0.3472762], [1544018118447071400,-0.901294,-1.0081239,1.1147203,2.4287946,4.0481615,8.595563,0.13102753,0.054328486,0.3472762], [1544018118450277441,-0.901294,-1.0081239,1.1147203,2.4287946,4.0481615,8.595563,0.11930962,0.056459017,0.33129725], [1544018118457295566,-0.901294,-1.0081239,1.1147203,2.4287946,4.0481615,8.595563,0.10333065,0.0628506,0.30786142], [1544018118457295566,-0.901294,-1.0081239,1.1147203,2.4354625,4.0480876,8.59371,0.10333065,0.0628506,0.30786142], [1544018118457295566,-0.90796185,-1.00805,1.1165733,2.4354625,4.0480876,8.59371,0.10333065,0.0628506,0.30786142], [1544018118460055045,-0.90796185,-1.00805,1.1165733,2.4354625,4.0480876,8.59371,0.08522116,0.070307456,0.29188246], [1544018118466424577,-0.90796185,-1.00805,1.1165733,2.4354625,4.0480876,8.59371,0.056459017,0.07350325,0.2876214], [1544018118466424577,-0.90796185,-1.00805,1.1165733,2.4375296,4.0499444,8.592251,0.056459017,0.07350325,0.2876214], [1544018118466424577,-0.91002893,-1.0099068,1.1180325,2.4375296,4.0499444,8.592251,0.056459017,0.07350325,0.2876214], [1544018118470205201,-0.91002893,-1.0099068,1.1180325,2.4375296,4.0499444,8.592251,0.025566347,0.07350325,0.28868666], [1544018118477761191,-0.91002893,-1.0099068,1.1180325,2.4375296,4.0499444,8.592251,-0.008522116,0.068176925,0.2908172], [1544018118477761191,-0.91002893,-1.0099068,1.1180325,2.4386032,4.046482,8.593576,-0.008522116,0.068176925,0.2908172], [1544018118477761191,-0.43226218,-0.12537837,0.010585785,2.4386032,4.046482,8.593576,-0.008522116,0.068176925,0.2908172], [1544018118479589472,-0.43226218,-0.12537837,0.010585785,2.4386032,4.046482,8.593576,-0.035153728,0.05539375,0.29507825], [1544018118486404368,-0.43226218,-0.12537837,0.010585785,2.4386032,4.046482,8.593576,-0.060720075,0.05006743,0.29507825], [1544018118486404368,-0.43226218,-0.12537837,0.010585785,2.4415185,4.0340786,8.5985775,-0.060720075,0.05006743,0.29507825], [1544018118486404368,-0.43517756,-0.11297488,0.005584717,2.4415185,4.0340786,8.5985775,-0.060720075,0.05006743,0.29507825], [1544018118489640722,-0.43517756,-0.11297488,0.005584717,2.4415185,4.0340786,8.5985775,-0.07882957,0.05219796,0.29188246], [1544018118497077129,-0.43517756,-0.11297488,0.005584717,2.4415185,4.0340786,8.5985775,-0.09374327,0.06498113,0.28549087], [1544018118497077129,-0.43517756,-0.11297488,0.005584717,2.4467154,4.018978,8.604171,-0.09374327,0.06498113,0.28549087], [1544018118497077129,-0.44037437,-0.0978744,-8.583069E-6,2.4467154,4.018978,8.604171,-0.09374327,0.06498113,0.28549087], [1544018118499279108,-0.44037437,-0.0978744,-8.583069E-6,2.4467154,4.018978,8.604171,-0.099069595,0.08522116,0.2727077], [1544018118506453431,-0.44037437,-0.0978744,-8.583069E-6,2.4467154,4.018978,8.604171,-0.096939065,0.10226539,0.25992453], [1544018118506453431,-0.44037437,-0.0978744,-8.583069E-6,2.4494827,4.003057,8.610802,-0.096939065,0.10226539,0.25992453], [1544018118506453431,-0.4431417,-0.08195329,-0.0066394806,2.4494827,4.003057,8.610802,-0.096939065,0.10226539,0.25992453], [1544018118509635618,-0.4431417,-0.08195329,-0.0066394806,2.4494827,4.003057,8.610802,-0.096939065,0.12463594,0.24181503], [1544018118516339577,-0.4431417,-0.08195329,-0.0066394806,2.4494827,4.003057,8.610802,-0.096939065,0.1470065,0.2247708], [1544018118516339577,-0.4431417,-0.08195329,-0.0066394806,2.445256,3.989594,8.618249,-0.096939065,0.1470065,0.2247708], [1544018118516339577,-0.438915,-0.06849027,-0.014086723,2.445256,3.989594,8.618249,-0.096939065,0.1470065,0.2247708], [1544018118519314681,-0.438915,-0.06849027,-0.014086723,2.445256,3.989594,8.618249,-0.096939065,0.16831179,0.21198763], [1544018118525881191,-0.438915,-0.06849027,-0.014086723,2.445256,3.989594,8.618249,-0.10226539,0.1949434,0.20240025], [1544018118525881191,-0.438915,-0.06849027,-0.014086723,2.4360445,3.9781215,8.626159,-0.10226539,0.1949434,0.20240025], [1544018118525881191,-0.42970347,-0.057017803,-0.021996498,2.4360445,3.9781215,8.626159,-0.10226539,0.1949434,0.20240025], [1544018118529498222,-0.42970347,-0.057017803,-0.021996498,2.4360445,3.9781215,8.626159,-0.1107875,0.22264028,0.19707392], [1544018118536617233,-0.42970347,-0.057017803,-0.021996498,2.4360445,3.9781215,8.626159,-0.1257012,0.25672874,0.19813919], [1544018118536617233,-0.42970347,-0.057017803,-0.021996498,2.4190898,3.9648137,8.637048,-0.1257012,0.25672874,0.19813919], [1544018118536617233,-0.4127488,-0.043709993,-0.03288555,2.4190898,3.9648137,8.637048,-0.1257012,0.25672874,0.19813919], [1544018118538981868,-0.4127488,-0.043709993,-0.03288555,2.4190898,3.9648137,8.637048,-0.14061491,0.294013,0.20133498], [1544018118545879629,-0.4127488,-0.043709993,-0.03288555,2.4190898,3.9648137,8.637048,-0.15765914,0.32810146,0.20772657], [1544018118545879629,-0.4127488,-0.043709993,-0.03288555,2.3945901,3.946945,8.652045,-0.15765914,0.32810146,0.20772657], [1544018118545879629,-0.38824916,-0.025841236,-0.047883034,2.3945901,3.946945,8.652045,-0.15765914,0.32810146,0.20772657], [1544018118549392753,-0.38824916,-0.025841236,-0.047883034,2.3945901,3.946945,8.652045,-0.17044231,0.36005938,0.21518342], [1544018118556227962,-0.38824916,-0.025841236,-0.047883034,2.3945901,3.946945,8.652045,-0.18216023,0.3898868,0.21411815], [1544018118556227962,-0.38824916,-0.025841236,-0.047883034,2.3663616,3.9264393,8.6691265,-0.18216023,0.3898868,0.21411815], [1544018118556227962,-0.36002064,-0.0053355694,-0.064964294,2.3663616,3.9264393,8.6691265,-0.18216023,0.3898868,0.21411815], [1544018118559142910,-0.36002064,-0.0053355694,-0.064964294,2.3663616,3.9264393,8.6691265,-0.1917476,0.41225734,0.21198763], [1544018118565734420,-0.36002064,-0.0053355694,-0.064964294,2.3663616,3.9264393,8.6691265,-0.19813919,0.44315,0.20026971], [1544018118565734420,-0.36002064,-0.0053355694,-0.064964294,2.3367333,3.9048707,8.686886,-0.19813919,0.44315,0.20026971], [1544018118565734420,-0.33039236,0.016232967,-0.08272362,2.3367333,3.9048707,8.686886,-0.19813919,0.44315,0.20026971], [1544018118568754472,-0.33039236,0.016232967,-0.08272362,2.3367333,3.9048707,8.686886,-0.19813919,0.44315,0.20026971], [1544018118576160409,-0.33039236,0.016232967,-0.08272362,2.3367333,3.9048707,8.686886,-0.21092236,0.49002165,0.17470337], [1544018118576160409,-0.33039236,0.016232967,-0.08272362,2.3001814,3.886472,8.704876,-0.21092236,0.49002165,0.17470337], [1544018118576160409,-0.2938404,0.03463173,-0.10071373,2.3001814,3.886472,8.704876,-0.21092236,0.49002165,0.17470337], [1544018118578444523,-0.2938404,0.03463173,-0.10071373,2.3001814,3.886472,8.704876,-0.21092236,0.49002165,0.17470337], [1544018118585175045,-0.2938404,0.03463173,-0.10071373,2.3001814,3.886472,8.704876,-0.23648871,0.49534798,0.15765914], [1544018118585175045,-0.2938404,0.03463173,-0.10071373,2.259726,3.870253,8.722679,-0.23648871,0.49534798,0.15765914], [1544018118585175045,-0.25338507,0.05085063,-0.11851692,2.259726,3.870253,8.722679,-0.23648871,0.49534798,0.15765914], [1544018118588436242,-0.25338507,0.05085063,-0.11851692,2.259726,3.870253,8.722679,-0.23648871,0.49534798,0.15765914], [1544018118596056867,-0.25338507,0.05085063,-0.11851692,2.259726,3.870253,8.722679,-0.26312032,0.44741106,0.15765914], [1544018118596056867,-0.25338507,0.05085063,-0.11851692,2.2181523,3.8527079,8.741097,-0.26312032,0.44741106,0.15765914], [1544018118596056867,-0.2118113,0.06839585,-0.13693523,2.2181523,3.8527079,8.741097,-0.26312032,0.44741106,0.15765914], [1544018118598674784,-0.2118113,0.06839585,-0.13693523,2.2181523,3.8527079,8.741097,-0.26312032,0.44741106,0.15765914], [1544018118604924576,-0.2118113,0.06839585,-0.13693523,2.2181523,3.8527079,8.741097,-0.2727077,0.36005938,0.16405073], [1544018118604924576,-0.2118113,0.06839585,-0.13693523,2.183723,3.8301568,8.759658,-0.2727077,0.36005938,0.16405073], [1544018118604924576,-0.17738199,0.09094691,-0.15549564,2.183723,3.8301568,8.759658,-0.2727077,0.36005938,0.16405073], [1544018118608370305,-0.17738199,0.09094691,-0.15549564,2.183723,3.8301568,8.759658,-0.2727077,0.36005938,0.16405073], [1544018119988939992,0.5091903,-0.3469162,0.29212952,2.3159678,4.564901,8.364705,-0.0031957934,-0.12463594,-0.18429075], [1544018119988939992,0.5091903,-0.3469162,0.29212952,2.3198545,4.57028,8.36069,-0.0031957934,-0.12463594,-0.18429075], [1544018119988939992,0.5053036,-0.3522954,0.2961445,2.3198545,4.57028,8.36069,-0.0031957934,-0.12463594,-0.18429075], [1544018119992435304,0.5053036,-0.3522954,0.2961445,2.3198545,4.57028,8.36069,-0.046871636,-0.12676647,-0.18748654], [1544018119999229211,0.5053036,-0.3522954,0.2961445,2.3198545,4.57028,8.36069,-0.083090626,-0.10013486,-0.1949434], [1544018119999229211,0.5053036,-0.3522954,0.2961445,2.322476,4.5734468,8.358232,-0.083090626,-0.10013486,-0.1949434], [1544018119999229211,0.5026822,-0.35546207,0.29860306,2.322476,4.5734468,8.358232,-0.083090626,-0.10013486,-0.1949434], [1544018120002188482,0.5026822,-0.35546207,0.29860306,2.322476,4.5734468,8.358232,-0.11930962,-0.07669904,-0.20240025], [1544018120009104732,0.5026822,-0.35546207,0.29860306,2.322476,4.5734468,8.358232,-0.15659387,-0.06498113,-0.21731395], [1544018120009104732,0.5026822,-0.35546207,0.29860306,2.3191912,4.5688114,8.361676,-0.15659387,-0.06498113,-0.21731395], [1544018120009104732,0.5059669,-0.35082674,0.2951584,2.3191912,4.5688114,8.361676,-0.15659387,-0.06498113,-0.21731395], [1544018120011903690,0.5059669,-0.35082674,0.2951584,2.3191912,4.5688114,8.361676,-0.19707392,-0.06498113,-0.23222765], [1544018120019006086,0.5059669,-0.35082674,0.2951584,2.3191912,4.5688114,8.361676,-0.23861924,-0.05965481,-0.24820662], [1544018120019006086,0.5059669,-0.35082674,0.2951584,2.3132215,4.5606236,8.367799,-0.23861924,-0.05965481,-0.24820662], [1544018120019006086,0.51193666,-0.34263897,0.2890358,2.3132215,4.5606236,8.367799,-0.23861924,-0.05965481,-0.24820662], [1544018120021601763,0.51193666,-0.34263897,0.2890358,2.3132215,4.5606236,8.367799,-0.23861924,-0.05965481,-0.24820662], [1544018120028990201,0.51193666,-0.34263897,0.2890358,2.3132215,4.5606236,8.367799,-0.32597092,-0.039414786,-0.26738137], [1544018120028990201,0.51193666,-0.34263897,0.2890358,2.3043458,4.546427,8.377965,-0.32597092,-0.039414786,-0.26738137], [1544018120028990201,0.5208123,-0.3284421,0.27886963,2.3043458,4.546427,8.377965,-0.32597092,-0.039414786,-0.26738137], [1544018120031596450,0.5208123,-0.3284421,0.27886963,2.3043458,4.546427,8.377965,-0.32597092,-0.039414786,-0.26738137], [1544018120038763690,0.5208123,-0.3284421,0.27886963,2.3043458,4.546427,8.377965,-0.40053943,-0.008522116,-0.2790993], [1544018120038763690,0.5208123,-0.3284421,0.27886963,2.2928727,4.525889,8.392221,-0.40053943,-0.008522116,-0.2790993], [1544018120038763690,0.53228545,-0.30790424,0.26461315,2.2928727,4.525889,8.392221,-0.40053943,-0.008522116,-0.2790993], [1544018120041472388,0.53228545,-0.30790424,0.26461315,2.2928727,4.525889,8.392221,-0.40053943,-0.008522116,-0.2790993], [1544018120048767284,0.53228545,-0.30790424,0.26461315,2.2928727,4.525889,8.392221,-0.4463458,0.010652645,-0.28868666], [1544018120048767284,0.53228545,-0.30790424,0.26461315,2.2782674,4.497842,8.411258,-0.4463458,0.010652645,-0.28868666], [1544018120048767284,0.54689074,-0.27985716,0.24557686,2.2782674,4.497842,8.411258,-0.4463458,0.010652645,-0.28868666], [1544018120051360825,0.54689074,-0.27985716,0.24557686,2.2782674,4.497842,8.411258,-0.4463458,0.010652645,-0.28868666], [1544018120058641346,0.54689074,-0.27985716,0.24557686,2.2782674,4.497842,8.411258,-0.46871635,0.0063915867,-0.2876214], [1544018120058641346,0.54689074,-0.27985716,0.24557686,2.2608988,4.4669447,8.432384,-0.46871635,0.0063915867,-0.2876214], [1544018120058641346,0.5642593,-0.24896002,0.22445107,2.2608988,4.4669447,8.432384,-0.46871635,0.0063915867,-0.2876214], [1544018120061514940,0.5642593,-0.24896002,0.22445107,2.2608988,4.4669447,8.432384,-0.46871635,0.0063915867,-0.2876214], [1544018120068548846,0.5642593,-0.24896002,0.22445107,2.2608988,4.4669447,8.432384,-0.48043427,-0.0010652645,-0.27483824], [1544018120068548846,0.5642593,-0.24896002,0.22445107,2.2451632,4.4361215,8.452833,-0.48043427,-0.0010652645,-0.27483824], [1544018120068548846,0.5799949,-0.21813679,0.20400143,2.2451632,4.4361215,8.452833,-0.48043427,-0.0010652645,-0.27483824], [1544018120071104992,0.5799949,-0.21813679,0.20400143,2.2451632,4.4361215,8.452833,-0.48043427,-0.0010652645,-0.27483824], [1544018120078947076,0.5799949,-0.21813679,0.20400143,2.2451632,4.4361215,8.452833,-0.48043427,-0.002130529,-0.2609898], [1544018120078947076,0.5799949,-0.21813679,0.20400143,2.2309904,4.4033804,8.47368,-0.48043427,-0.002130529,-0.2609898], [1544018120078947076,-0.23422623,0.13542747,0.0059843063,2.2309904,4.4033804,8.47368,-0.48043427,-0.002130529,-0.2609898], [1544018120081702440,-0.23422623,0.13542747,0.0059843063,2.2309904,4.4033804,8.47368,-0.47830373,0.0031957934,-0.2545982], [1544018120088157024,-0.23422623,0.13542747,0.0059843063,2.2309904,4.4033804,8.47368,-0.47723848,0.0010652645,-0.2545982], [1544018120088157024,-0.23422623,0.13542747,0.0059843063,2.217916,4.371229,8.493736,-0.47723848,0.0010652645,-0.2545982], [1544018120088157024,-0.22115183,0.1675787,-0.014072418,2.217916,4.371229,8.493736,-0.47723848,0.0010652645,-0.2545982], [1544018120090956919,-0.22115183,0.1675787,-0.014072418,2.217916,4.371229,8.493736,-0.47723848,0.0010652645,-0.2545982], [1544018120097697597,-0.22115183,0.1675787,-0.014072418,2.217916,4.371229,8.493736,-0.47830373,0.010652645,-0.25672874], [1544018120097697597,-0.22115183,0.1675787,-0.014072418,2.2046096,4.3372436,8.514597,-0.47830373,0.010652645,-0.25672874], [1544018120097697597,-0.20784545,0.20156431,-0.03493309,2.2046096,4.3372436,8.514597,-0.47830373,0.010652645,-0.25672874], [1544018120101215200,-0.20784545,0.20156431,-0.03493309,2.2046096,4.3372436,8.514597,-0.47830373,0.010652645,-0.25672874], [1544018120107980617,-0.20784545,0.20156431,-0.03493309,2.2046096,4.3372436,8.514597,-0.48363006,0.017044231,-0.26312032], [1544018120107980617,-0.20784545,0.20156431,-0.03493309,2.190108,4.3015656,8.536409,-0.48363006,0.017044231,-0.26312032], [1544018120107980617,-0.19334388,0.23724222,-0.05674553,2.190108,4.3015656,8.536409,-0.48363006,0.017044231,-0.26312032], [1544018120110745982,-0.19334388,0.23724222,-0.05674553,2.190108,4.3015656,8.536409,-0.49002165,0.029827405,-0.2727077], [1544018120117943534,-0.19334388,0.23724222,-0.05674553,2.190108,4.3015656,8.536409,-0.49960902,0.05539375,-0.28442562], [1544018120117943534,-0.19334388,0.23724222,-0.05674553,2.1718931,4.2650795,8.559341,-0.49960902,0.05539375,-0.28442562], [1544018120117943534,-0.17512894,0.27372837,-0.07967758,2.1718931,4.2650795,8.559341,-0.49960902,0.05539375,-0.28442562], [1544018120120634315,-0.17512894,0.27372837,-0.07967758,2.1718931,4.2650795,8.559341,-0.51452273,0.068176925,-0.2972088], [1544018120127794940,-0.17512894,0.27372837,-0.07967758,2.1718931,4.2650795,8.559341,-0.52837116,0.08841695,-0.30999196], [1544018120127794940,-0.17512894,0.27372837,-0.07967758,2.1506958,4.2254825,8.584297,-0.52837116,0.08841695,-0.30999196], [1544018120127794940,-0.15393162,0.3133254,-0.10463333,2.1506958,4.2254825,8.584297,-0.52837116,0.08841695,-0.30999196], [1544018120130230200,-0.15393162,0.3133254,-0.10463333,2.1506958,4.2254825,8.584297,-0.54435015,0.1107875,-0.32597092], [1544018120137752076,-0.15393162,0.3133254,-0.10463333,2.1506958,4.2254825,8.584297,-0.5539375,0.13741912,-0.34940675], [1544018120137752076,-0.15393162,0.3133254,-0.10463333,2.1265657,4.182562,8.611286,-0.5539375,0.13741912,-0.34940675], [1544018120137752076,-0.12980151,0.356246,-0.13162231,2.1265657,4.182562,8.611286,-0.5539375,0.13741912,-0.34940675], [1544018120140247909,-0.12980151,0.356246,-0.13162231,2.1265657,4.182562,8.611286,-0.5571333,0.16724652,-0.3749731], [1544018120147915461,-0.12980151,0.356246,-0.13162231,2.1265657,4.182562,8.611286,-0.5411543,0.23435818,-0.43782368], [1544018120147915461,-0.12980151,0.356246,-0.13162231,2.0961964,4.1390033,8.639733,-0.5411543,0.23435818,-0.43782368], [1544018120147915461,-0.09943223,0.3998046,-0.16006947,2.0961964,4.1390033,8.639733,-0.5411543,0.23435818,-0.43782368], [1544018120150245825,-0.09943223,0.3998046,-0.16006947,2.0961964,4.1390033,8.639733,-0.5411543,0.23435818,-0.43782368], [1544018120157185774,-0.09943223,0.3998046,-0.16006947,2.0961964,4.1390033,8.639733,-0.5336975,0.26312032,-0.46871635], [1544018120157185774,-0.09943223,0.3998046,-0.16006947,2.056826,4.1001678,8.667666,-0.5336975,0.26312032,-0.46871635], [1544018120157185774,-0.06006193,0.43864012,-0.18800259,2.056826,4.1001678,8.667666,-0.5336975,0.26312032,-0.46871635], [1544018120160199315,-0.06006193,0.43864012,-0.18800259,2.056826,4.1001678,8.667666,-0.52624065,0.30040458,-0.49641323], [1544018120167083586,-0.06006193,0.43864012,-0.18800259,2.056826,4.1001678,8.667666,-0.5219796,0.33449304,-0.5219796], [1544018120167083586,-0.06006193,0.43864012,-0.18800259,2.0083225,4.065857,8.695161,-0.5219796,0.33449304,-0.5219796], [1544018120167083586,-0.011558294,0.47295094,-0.21549702,2.0083225,4.065857,8.695161,-0.5219796,0.33449304,-0.5219796], [1544018120170092180,-0.011558294,0.47295094,-0.21549702,2.0083225,4.065857,8.695161,-0.5219796,0.3685815,-0.5454154], [1544018120177251867,-0.011558294,0.47295094,-0.21549702,2.0083225,4.065857,8.695161,-0.5230448,0.40586576,-0.56885123], [1544018120177251867,-0.011558294,0.47295094,-0.21549702,1.9483682,4.030423,8.725245,-0.5230448,0.40586576,-0.56885123], [1544018120177251867,0.04839599,0.5083847,-0.24558163,1.9483682,4.030423,8.725245,-0.5230448,0.40586576,-0.56885123], [1544018120179816971,0.04839599,0.5083847,-0.24558163,1.9483682,4.030423,8.725245,-0.5273059,0.43782368,-0.588026], [1544018120187149472,0.04839599,0.5083847,-0.24558163,1.9483682,4.030423,8.725245,-0.5336975,0.46871635,-0.6040049], [1544018120187149472,0.04839599,0.5083847,-0.24558163,1.8800789,3.9971027,8.755504,-0.5336975,0.46871635,-0.6040049], [1544018120187149472,0.11668527,0.54170513,-0.2758398,1.8800789,3.9971027,8.755504,-0.5336975,0.46871635,-0.6040049], [1544018120189667180,0.11668527,0.54170513,-0.2758398,1.8800789,3.9971027,8.755504,-0.535828,0.49215218,-0.62104917], [1544018120196879628,0.11668527,0.54170513,-0.2758398,1.8800789,3.9971027,8.755504,-0.5336975,0.5091964,-0.63383234], [1544018120196879628,0.11668527,0.54170513,-0.2758398,1.8038359,3.9651248,8.78603,-0.5336975,0.5091964,-0.63383234], [1544018120196879628,0.19292831,0.573683,-0.30636597,1.8038359,3.9651248,8.78603,-0.5336975,0.5091964,-0.63383234], [1544018120199769523,0.19292831,0.573683,-0.30636597,1.8038359,3.9651248,8.78603,-0.52624065,0.5209143,-0.6402239], [1544018133060332643,-0.10242605,-0.023055553,0.27135754,-0.6780837,3.618548,9.089373,0.025566347,0.12250541,0.01917476], [1544018133060332643,-0.10242605,-0.023055553,0.27135754,-0.6890388,3.6247625,9.086071,0.025566347,0.12250541,0.01917476], [1544018133060332643,-0.09147096,-0.029270172,0.27465916,-0.6890388,3.6247625,9.086071,0.025566347,0.12250541,0.01917476], [1544018133065493581,-0.09147096,-0.029270172,0.27465916,-0.6890388,3.6247625,9.086071,0.029827405,0.16724652,0.01917476], [1544018133070919206,-0.09147096,-0.029270172,0.27465916,-0.6890388,3.6247625,9.086071,0.017044231,0.19068234,0.027696876], [1544018133070919206,-0.09147096,-0.029270172,0.27465916,-0.7049035,3.6281376,9.083506,0.017044231,0.19068234,0.027696876], [1544018133070919206,0.015373409,0.22114015,-0.9533949,-0.7049035,3.6281376,9.083506,0.017044231,0.19068234,0.027696876], [1544018133075239727,0.015373409,0.22114015,-0.9533949,-0.7049035,3.6281376,9.083506,-0.0127831735,0.1949434,0.029827405], [1544018133080645925,0.015373409,0.22114015,-0.9533949,-0.7049035,3.6281376,9.083506,-0.043675844,0.17044231,0.027696876], [1544018133080645925,0.015373409,0.22114015,-0.9533949,-0.72076136,3.623372,9.084165,-0.043675844,0.17044231,0.027696876], [1544018133080645925,0.031231284,0.22590566,-0.9540539,-0.72076136,3.623372,9.084165,-0.043675844,0.17044231,0.027696876], [1544018133084872331,0.031231284,0.22590566,-0.9540539,-0.72076136,3.623372,9.084165,-0.0628506,0.14061491,0.029827405], [1544018133090757435,0.031231284,0.22590566,-0.9540539,-0.72076136,3.623372,9.084165,-0.07669904,0.10759171,0.029827405], [1544018133090757435,0.031231284,0.22590566,-0.9540539,-0.7295929,3.6132548,9.087489,-0.07669904,0.10759171,0.029827405], [1544018133090757435,0.040062845,0.23602295,-0.9573784,-0.7295929,3.6132548,9.087489,-0.07669904,0.10759171,0.029827405], [1544018133094886758,0.040062845,0.23602295,-0.9573784,-0.7295929,3.6132548,9.087489,-0.082025364,0.068176925,0.03089267], [1544018133100354206,0.040062845,0.23602295,-0.9573784,-0.7295929,3.6132548,9.087489,-0.08522116,0.02130529,0.034088463], [1544018133100354206,0.040062845,0.23602295,-0.9573784,-0.72885966,3.600863,9.092464,-0.08522116,0.02130529,0.034088463], [1544018133100354206,0.03932959,0.24841475,-0.9623537,-0.72885966,3.600863,9.092464,-0.08522116,0.02130529,0.034088463], [1544018133104953321,0.03932959,0.24841475,-0.9623537,-0.72885966,3.600863,9.092464,-0.08522116,-0.027696876,0.03195793], [1544018133110384727,0.03932959,0.24841475,-0.9623537,-0.72885966,3.600863,9.092464,-0.07456851,-0.070307456,0.029827405], [1544018133110384727,0.03932959,0.24841475,-0.9623537,-0.7202974,3.5899224,9.097471,-0.07456851,-0.070307456,0.029827405], [1544018133110384727,0.030767322,0.2593553,-0.9673605,-0.7202974,3.5899224,9.097471,-0.07456851,-0.070307456,0.029827405], [1544018133114630613,0.030767322,0.2593553,-0.9673605,-0.7202974,3.5899224,9.097471,-0.05965481,-0.10546118,0.027696876], [1544018133120115300,0.030767322,0.2593553,-0.9673605,-0.7202974,3.5899224,9.097471,-0.040480047,-0.13315806,0.025566347], [1544018133120115300,0.030767322,0.2593553,-0.9673605,-0.7060047,3.580631,9.102253,-0.040480047,-0.13315806,0.025566347], [1544018133120115300,0.016474605,0.26864672,-0.9721422,-0.7060047,3.580631,9.102253,-0.040480047,-0.13315806,0.025566347], [1544018133124657071,0.016474605,0.26864672,-0.9721422,-0.7060047,3.580631,9.102253,-0.025566347,-0.15446335,0.023435818], [1544018133130556081,0.016474605,0.26864672,-0.9721422,-0.7060047,3.580631,9.102253,-0.00958738,-0.16724652,0.023435818], [1544018133130556081,0.016474605,0.26864672,-0.9721422,-0.68643755,3.5784667,9.1046,-0.00958738,-0.16724652,0.023435818], [1544018133130556081,-0.0030925274,0.27081108,-0.9744892,-0.68643755,3.5784667,9.1046,-0.00958738,-0.16724652,0.023435818], [1544018133134612644,-0.0030925274,0.27081108,-0.9744892,-0.68643755,3.5784667,9.1046,0.0031957934,-0.16724652,0.01917476], [1544018133139897123,-0.0030925274,0.27081108,-0.9744892,-0.68643755,3.5784667,9.1046,0.017044231,-0.13954964,0.0127831735], [1544018133139897123,-0.0030925274,0.27081108,-0.9744892,-0.6709813,3.578292,9.10582,0.017044231,-0.13954964,0.0127831735], [1544018133139897123,-0.018548787,0.27098584,-0.97570896,-0.6709813,3.578292,9.10582,0.017044231,-0.13954964,0.0127831735], [1544018133144019988,-0.018548787,0.27098584,-0.97570896,-0.6709813,3.578292,9.10582,0.027696876,-0.10759171,0.0063915867]]"

$userId
[1] "123"

$deviceId
[1] "3892502a-9358-4c11-9fc4-b5ca151370c3"

$uuid
[1] "d79f206ab25113a8"

$version
[1] "1.0.1"
```

I am taking the `eventList` field:

`j$eventList` and want to make it as dataframe.

But when I am trying to do this using `fromJSON` the output is different numbers:

```
            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]       [,4] [,5]       [,6] [,7]
 [1,] 1544018118438041088 162.0000 38.00000 0.02352941    1 2131230815    1
 [2,] 1544018118466235904 162.0000 38.00000 0.02549020    1 2131230815    0
 [3,] 1544018118586849792 161.0517 36.05170 0.02352941    1 2131230815    0
 [4,] 1544018118601169152 158.0131 33.01306 0.02745098    1 2131230815    0
 [5,] 1544018118612947456 157.0000 32.00000 0.03137255    1 2131230815    0
 [6,] 1544018118614422272 157.0000 32.00000 0.03137255    1 2131230815   -1
 [7,] 1544018119991079424 195.0000 27.00000 0.02352941    1 2131230815    1
 [8,] 1544018120055418624 195.0000 27.00000 0.02549020    1 2131230815    0
 [9,] 1544018120073841664 195.0000 27.00000 0.02745098    1 2131230815    0
[10,] 1544018120105393152 195.0000 29.16931 0.02745098    1 2131230815    0
[11,] 1544018120142059776 195.0000 30.21478 0.02745098    1 2131230815    0
[12,] 1544018120156259584 194.2148 31.00000 0.02549020    1 2131230815    0
[13,] 1544018120182791680 192.3903 31.30487 0.02549020    1 2131230815    0
[14,] 1544018120190025472 187.7406 32.81482 0.02352941    1 2131230815    0
[15,] 1544018120205907200 179.2196 35.59345 0.03137255    1 2131230815    0
[16,] 1544018120207792384 179.2196 35.59345 0.03137255    1 2131230815   -1
[17,] 1544018133062822656 536.0000 86.00000 0.02549020    1 2131230776    1
[18,] 1544018133093266688 535.0000 86.00000 0.02549020    1 2131230776    0
[19,] 1544018133143500800 535.0000 86.00000 0.02941177    1 2131230776    0
[20,] 1544018133147562240 535.0000 86.00000 0.02941177    1 2131230776   -1
```

Why the `timestamp` changed (the first value in each row):
1544018118438041088 vs. 1544018118438041139

Please advise how to transfer it to a `dataframe` with the same numbers as the origin?

Comment: please provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). As of now, your question would get closed due to NO MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a rounding error to me, as you have an awful lot of digits. I guess in order to even show your data.frame you had to specify that you wanted a lot of digits, and in the documentation for `?print` it says

"Note that for large values of digits, currently for digits >= 16, the calculation of the number of significant digits will depend on the platform's internal (C library) implementation of sprintf() functionality."

So the question is what you actually want to do with the data. Assuming your first value means "2018-12-05 13:55:18 UTC", you have nano-second precision specified, and there are rounding errors in the ~100 ns-scale. Is that a problem?

If you have experiments that are very time-sensitive, I suggest choosing a different t=0, then your precision improves. If you want just the import to go right I suggest telling `fromJSON` you want it as a character (the docs are not very clear, but `bigint_as_char=TRUE` does the trick).
That's also the most useful if you just want to use it as a kind of ID.